# jQuery Animate translateY Based On Scroll Percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple overlapping "parallax" effect without any plugins.  I have html like:

```
<section>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Example Text</h2>
</section>
```

Each section has a height of 100% of the viewport.  I'm using an each loop inside `$(window).scroll()`.  I need to animate the `transform: translateY()` property of the top section until the following section is at the top of the browser.  This percentage essentially needs to be based on the percetange from the top of the browser. I've tried a number of things involving getting the `offset().top`, and `height()` values, and comparing them to `$(window).scrollTop()` but I can't seem to work it out.  This is the effect I'm trying to achieve, though its using a jQuery plugin.

http://codepen.io/rocbear/pen/bdIaG

**Edit**
I have this almost worked out now, but I have one small issue scroll back to the top.  The `translate` property doesn't go all the way back to 0% and leaves a gap at the top.

My codepen: http://codepen.io/mdmoore/pen/MwjoLZ

```
$(function(){
  $('section').each(function() {
    var off = $(this).offset().top
    $(this).data('orig-offset', off);
  });
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('section').each(function(){
      var off = $(this).data('orig-offset');
      var translate =  (scrollTop - off) / $(window).height() * 100;
      if (scrollTop >= off) {
        $(this).css({transform: 'translateY(' + translate +'%)'});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Change `if (scrollTop > off)` to `if (scrollTop >= off)`

Comment: That does it.  I should've realized that.  If you want to update your answer with my final code, I'll accept it since its based so much on your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your final code, but using nth-of-type instead of nth-child because the required script include was causing it to fail otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way.  Feel free to optimize it if you want.

```js
$(function(){
  $('section').each(function() {
    var off = $(this).offset().top
    $(this).data('orig-offset', off);
  });
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

     $('section').each(function(){
      var off = $(this).data('orig-offset');
      
       
      if (scrollTop >= off) {
        var translate =  (scrollTop - off) / $(window).height() * 100;
        console.log(translate);
        $(this).css({transform: 'translateY(' + translate +'%)'});
      }
     });
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
section:first-of-type {
  background-color: coral;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #ffff6e;
}
section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="top">
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer has helped me get very close to what I'm going for.  I've updated updated my question and included my current progress and one small issue I have.