# Translate on scroll in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I need help regarding the translate-animate property. 
There's an image I want to translate in the upward direction when I scroll down on the page. 
Now I know I can use the property translateY(px) to move it but then I don't know how to translateY while scrolling. 
I want to make my webpage look like this

https://www.apple.com/uk/iphone/

As you can see when you scroll down the image translates upwards with a smooth flow. 
I need a code such that I can translate my image upward smoothly on scrolling down.

P.s- This is my first question, sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378722/jquery-animate-translatey-based-on-scroll-percentage

Answer (score 1):

This is rather cheap parallax effect that I made myself but does not require any special magic to work... [Link to my original demo page](https://nightkn8.github.io/pure/html/demo1.html)

```js
let $scrollPrev = 0;
const $viewBottom = () => $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight(),
  $parallaxIllusion = () => {
    const $pxTop = $(".parallaxTop"),
      $pxMid = $(".parallaxMiddle"),
      $pxBottom = $(".parallaxBottom"),
      $scrollCurr = $viewBottom(),
      $bodyTop = $("body").offset().top,
      $bodyBottom = $bodyTop + $("body").outerHeight(true),
      $pxspeed = $scrollCurr - $bodyTop;
    if ($bodyTop > 0 && $viewBottom() > $bodyTop && $(window).scrollTop() <= $bodyBottom) {
      $pxTop.css({
        "top": 40 + -$pxspeed / 4
      });
      $pxMid.css({
        "top": $pxspeed / 2
      });
      $pxBottom.css({
        "top": ($pxspeed / 4)
      });
      $scrollPrev = $scrollCurr;
    };
  };

$(document).ready(() => {

  $(window).scroll(() => {
    $parallaxIllusion();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
height:700px;
}
.parallaxTop {
  background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NightKn8/pure/master/img/demo1/pxHand.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  width: 403px;
  height: 298px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallaxMiddle {
  background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NightKn8/pure/master/img/demo1/pxCaps.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  width: 109px;
  height: 117px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallaxBottom {
  background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NightKn8/pure/master/img/demo1/pxBeer.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  width: 406px;
  height: 443px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="parallaxTop"></div>
  <div class="parallaxMiddle"></div>
  <div class="parallaxBottom"></div>
</body>
```

Note that you can edit the code to peak 1 image. Speed or direction is controlled at `if` level.